# Does entrySet() in a LinkedHashMap also guarantee order?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I am using a linkedHashMap to guarantee order when someone tries to access it. However, when it comes time to iterate over it, does using entrySet() to return key/value pairs guarantee order as well? No changes will be made while iterating.

**EDIT:** Also, are there any adverse effects from iterating through the map by iterating through its keys and calling get?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, but why ask it if someone else already asked and received a good answer? +1 for a good question.

Comment: In LinkedHashMap you can use insert-order and access-order. The order is maintained always. Please cover my [Internal life of LinkedHashMap](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-linkedhashmap-in-java.html) tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the order guaranteed for the return of keys and values from a LinkedHashMap object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923856/is-the-order-guaranteed-for-the-return-of-keys-and-values-from-a-linkedhashmap-o)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), yes.

> This implementation differs from `HashMap` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*).

As for the edit, no, it should work just fine. But the entry set is somewhat faster since it avoids the overhead of looking up every key in the map during iteration.

Comment: but entrySet returns a Set which is unordered itself?

Comment: Yes, technically the entrySet itself has no way to access access a position, but entrySet.iterator() does. The iterator lets us have an ordered list.

Comment: I would like to know that this answer is correct, but as Jonathan pointed out, `entrySet()` returns a Set. Jpatrick says the set's iterator lets us have an ordered list, but http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator() says "The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee)." And none of the docs referenced here say that entrySet() returns a Set that's an instance of a class that guarantees order. Am I missing something?

Comment: Michael Myers is right to point out the documentation that says the LinkedHashMap defines an iteration ordering, but it doesn't say how to access that ordering. `entrySet().iterator()` is a plausible way, but can it be relied upon?

Comment: Found a definitive answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924143/423105 "The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements." -- javadoc for `Map`

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure no changes will be made during the iteration, then proper ordering with `entrySet()` is guaranteed, as stated in the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29).

Comment: The API docs that you linked to for `entrySet()` don't say anything about guaranteeing proper ordering. The only related statement on that page is "This class [i.e. HashMap] makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time." What were you referring to with that link?

Answer (score 1):

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)