# Is the order guaranteed for the return of keys and values from a LinkedHashMap object?

Tags: java, iteration, linkedhashmap

I know `LinkedHashMap` has a predictable iteration order (insertion order). Does the `Set` returned by `LinkedHashMap.keySet()` and the `Collection` returned by `LinkedHashMap.values()` also maintain this order?

Comment: Since all the answers address the issue of `values()` as well as `keySet()`, I've expanded the question to include that. This means more questions can be closed as duplicates of this.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

> The Map interface provides three
>   *collection views*, which allow a map's contents to be viewed as a set
>   of keys, collection of values, or set
>   of key-value mappings. The *order* of
>   a map is defined as the order in which
>   the iterators on the map's collection
>   views return their elements. Some map
>   implementations, like the `TreeMap`
>   class, make specific guarantees as to
>   their order; others, like the
>   `HashMap` class, do not.

-- [Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

> This linked list defines the iteration
>   ordering, which is normally the order
>   in which keys were inserted into the
>   map (*insertion-order*).

-- [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

So, yes, `keySet()`, `values()`, and `entrySet()` (the three collection views mentioned) return values in the order the internal linked list uses.  And yes, the JavaDoc for `Map` and `LinkedHashMap` guarantee it.

That is the point of this class, after all.

Comment: the iteration over the map is also done faster using a LinkedHashMap than a HashMap.

Comment: @Thierry: Yeah, I should have mentioned that.  Whoops.

Comment: values() returns a collection. not a List. how does it keep it in order?

Comment: @Dejel `Collection` is just the base class for what values() returns.  The implementation of the Collection it returns is still controlled by the `LinkedHashMap`.  In `LinkedHashMap`'s case, it's returning a [`LinkedValues`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#l584) instance, a private class inside LinkedHashMap.java.

Comment: A LinkedHashMap's keyset in my case is NOT in the order represented in the map. Very puzzled by this.

Comment: Thank you for linking to documentation (from `Map`) that explicitly ties the order of a map to the iterators on the map's collection views (and making clear what those collection views are). That was the missing piece for me.

Comment: @Amalgovinus: this is weird, according to the source code, it returns a `LinkedEntrySet` (though the javadoc only specifies it returns a `Set`, and `Set`s are not supposed to have iteration order guarantee, so the doc could be clearer). See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#LinkedHashMap.entrySet%28%29

Comment: @FBB `Set` doesn't have an order guarantee, but implementations can if they so choose. `LinkedHashMap.Entry` is an internal class used for entries in a `LinkedHashMap`.  As you might expect from it being a doubly linked list, each one stores a reference to the previous and next items.  `LinkedIterator` explicitly uses the next entry during iteration and each of the 3 `Set`s iterators inherit from that.

Comment: @Powerlord: I think you replied to the version of my comment before I edited it.

Comment: @Powerlord Although _"the JavaDoc for Map and LinkedHashMap guarantee it"_ I think it wouldn't hurt to reinforce it in `LinkedHashMap` javadoc. I think the reason people come to this post is because it's not that easy to figure the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the source, it looks like it does. `keySet()`, `values()`, and `entrySet()` all use the same entry iterator internally.

Comment: It would be cool to have a link to the repos, but I'm lazy :-) and of course, it's not guarantee of forward compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

Don't get confused with `LinkedHashMap.keySet()` and `LinkedHashMap.entrySet()` returning Set and hence it should not guarantee ordering !

`Set` is an interface with `HashSet`,`TreeSet` etc beings its implementations. The `HashSet` implementation of `Set` interface does not guarantees ordering. But `TreeSet` does. Also `LinkedHashSet` does.

Therefore it depends on how `Set` has been implemented in `LinkedHashMap` to know whether the returning Set reference will guarantee ordering or not. 
I went through the source code of `LinkedHashMap`, it looks like this:

```
private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {...}
public abstract class AbstractSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements Set<E> {...}
```

Thus LinkedHashMap/HashMap has its own implementation of `Set` i.e. `KeySet`. Thus don't confuse this with `HashSet`.

Also, the order is maintained by how the elements are inserted into the bucket. Look at the `addEntry(..)` method of `LinkedHashMap` and compare it with that of `HashMap` which highlights the main difference between `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: While this answer definitely presents useful information, it doesn't really answer the question. It is basically saying they CAN have predictable iteration order.

Answer (score 5):

You can assume so. The Javadoc says 'predictable iteration order', and the only iterators available in a Map *are* those for the keySet(), entrySet(), and values().

So in the absence of any further qualification it is clearly intended to apply to all of those iterators.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not documented so you cannot "formally" assume so. It is unlikely, however, that the current implementation would change.

If you want to ensure order, you may want to iterate over the map entires and insert them into a sorted set with an order function of your choice, though you will be paying a performance cost, naturally.

Comment: Do you mean entrySet() guarantees the order, by keySet() doesn't?

Comment: @kknight: I'm not sure. the javadoc states: "This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).". However, the JavaDocs for the JDK are very ambiguous in general.

Comment: If even entrySet() doesn't guarantee the iteration order, then what is the difference between LinkedHashMap and HashMap? How can we take advantage of the predictable iteration order in a LinkedHashMap instance?

Comment: It most certainly *is* documented. Answer is completely incorrect.