# Behaviour of LinkedHashMap's keySet() and values() methods

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the order guaranteed for the return of keySet() of a LinkedHashMap object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923856/is-the-order-guaranteed-for-the-return-of-keyset-of-a-linkedhashmap-object)

Consider I create a LinkedHashMap, like the following:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", "aa");
map.put("b", "bb");
map.put("c", "cc");
```

When I call `keySet()`, does that give me an ordered set? And if I call `values()`, are these ordered too?

**EDIT**

Sry, meant ordered, not sorted.

Comment: It's not a contract written in [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29). All it guarantees is a Set interface.

Comment: Why not [Use The Source, Luke](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java.util/LinkedHashMap.java.html)?

Comment: @DNA the link you gave is now broken :(

Comment: @GreenGiant Google is your friend ;-) try [this one](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.html) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all `LinkedHashMap` is *ordered* but not *sorted*. `TreeMap` is *sorted* (and hence *ordered* as well).

That being said you can not expect the output of `keySet()` and `values()` to be sorted. Actually the JavaDoc says <del>nothing about the order</del> (as it turns out, the order *is* guaranteed by JavaDoc: [Is the order guaranteed for the return of keys and values from a LinkedHashMap object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923856)) of these collections, however looking at the implementation they should follow the order of underlying `Map`.

To address recent edit to your question: it is not part of the contract, in fact `LinkedHashMap` does not even implement `keySet()` and `values()` but uses base classes's (`HashMap`) version. Even though based on the implementation you can see the order is preserved, you should not depend on it if you want your application to be portable.

Comment: Please look at the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923856/is-the-order-guaranteed-for-the-return-of-keyset-of-a-linkedhashmap-object

Comment: @ArneEvertsson: +1, thanks, corrected my answer. In fact I marked this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a `SortedSet` or a sorted collection when retrieving the key set or the values. However, the returned implementations use the map's key/value iterators and thus would return the values in the order of insertion, e.g. when being used in a foreach loop.

Thus you get the order as defined by the `LinkedHashMap` but you can not necessarily consider that to be sorted (and you can't resort those collections either).