# Will hashmap.keyset() return keys in the order they were added to the hashmap?

Tags: java

I know that the `.keySet()` returns a set, which is un-ordered.

As far as I can tell, that means I need to keep an array list of keys in order to track the order in which the keys were added to the hashmap, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behaviour of LinkedHashMap's keySet() and values() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583650/behaviour-of-linkedhashmaps-keyset-and-values-methods)

Comment: This is rather a remark on the "Behaviour of *HashMap's* keySet method" though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [...] *that means I need to keep an array list of keys in order to track the order in which the keys were added to the hashmap, correct?*

Yes, that's correct. Or, you could use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which does this for you.

From the documentation:

> [...] This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, **which is normally the order in which keys were inserted** into the map (insertion-order). [...]

Comment: Another possibility is a TreeMap. Note that all these classes do is guarantee that iteration will be in order, not that the Set returned by keySet() will have any particular order.

Comment: linked hashmap looks like what i need. How do I override removeEldestEntry so that it goes by insertion order only--not access order?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what you mean by access-order. The eldest entry is probably the key that was first inserted.

Comment: @TedHopp, TreeMap doesn't bother about insertion order.

Comment: ok. so if I use a linkedhashmap it goes by insertion order by default.

Comment: @aioobe - Right about a TreeMap. I don't know where that came from.