# How to iterate over Collection of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I have something like

```
Collection<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> responseObjects = (Collection<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>) response.getResponseObjects();
```

I am writing some unit tests where I am getting 2 elements in this collection and want to put assertions on each element Collection having a map of `<String,Object>`.
Both elements have different sets of values in `LinkedHashMap`.

I tried using For-Each

```
for(Map<String,Object> response : responseObjects) {
     assertEquals("Test", responseObj.get("stringField"));
}
```

But how do I control the index from this, since I need to put assertion on different data coming in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through LinkedHashMap with lists as values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310914/how-to-iterate-through-linkedhashmap-with-lists-as-values)

Comment: Actually, there is no notion of index in java.util.Collection but you can simply increment a local variable to get the job done, it just looks weird and not the right way to go in my humble opinion. You should use a List instead of a Collection if indexes matter.

Comment: The notion of `index` is applicable **only** if you're dialing with a `List` interface. With `Collection` it doesn't make sense.

Comment: A Collection does not guarantee to traverse in a predictable order.

Comment: @gouessej I ended up using a local variable to achieve the test result. But yes I agree with other suggestions to go with List interface to deal with index. Thanks!