# Does an ArrayList created from the keySet() of LinkedHashMap preserves the order of insertion?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I get data something like

> {"Employee 1 of ABC", "ABCX"}, {"Employee 2 of ABC", "ABCY"},
>   {"Employee 3 of ABC", "ABCZ"}

from database through a `RefCursor`.

I have a case where I need to preserve the order in which data is read from the database.
Since my data is kind of 'key-value' ,I thought of using a implementation of `Map` which is ordered. Hence chose `LinkedHashMap`

```
//defined as a static map inside a common utlity class
public class Common{
public static final LinkedHashMap<String, String> empMap = new   LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
}

//rs is the resultset
if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                key = rs.getString("name_text");
                value = rs.getString("id");
                Common.empMap.put(key, value);
            }
}
```

I have to pass the keys to the client, in the same order in which it was retrieved from the database (Cursor).

```
List<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>(Common.empMap.keySet());
```

> keySet() - The documentation says "Returns a Set view of the keys
>   contained in this map.            The set is backed by the map, so changes to
>   the map are reflected in the set,             and vice-versa"

What I expect is that Since `ArrayList` is also an ordered collection, I should get the keys in the same way in which it was retrieved/inserted into the `Map`.

When I do a sample test program, I am getting as expected.

```
public class LinkedMap {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();        
        map.put("Employee 1 of ABC", "ABCX");
        map.put("Employee 2 of ABC", "ABCY");
        map.put("Employee 3 of ABC", "ABCZ");   
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());   
        System.out.println(list);   
    }
}
```

> output:   [Employee 1 of ABC, Employee 2 of ABC, Employee 3 of ABC]

However my **question** is , if this is guaranteed output or is it that I am getting just randomly, and it might vary(?),

- update 09/14/2019

I am separating the answer from the question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I like how the variable type is the most specific `LinkedHashMap`, instead of a vague `Map` :)

Comment: I think , having the interface or the concrete class reference doesn't make a difference to my use case. But I must admit that it was a mistake to use the concrete class rather than interface. Or do you feel different?

Comment: no, I think it's best to use the most specific type for local/instance variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* guaranteed.

Even though the `Set` interface in itself doesn't guarantee any order (well, `LinkedHashSet` does), the fact that the `Map` implementation itself guarantees insertion ordering pretty much guarantees that you will get the keys in this order as well. The interface returned by `.keySet()` just happens to be a `Set` since, well, keys in a `Map` are guaranteed to be unique.

If it weren't, consider what would happen in this situation:

```
// case 1
for (final Map.Entry<K, V> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    // entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()
}

// case 2
for (final K key: map.keySet()) {
    V value = map.get(key);
}
```

If these two codes had two different behaviors, uh...

Comment: Thank you +1, "The interface returned by .keySet() just happens to be a Set" - thinking of this  `Set` was what confused me

Comment: Well, what if those two pieces of code iterated in a different order? Or even .values()?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is guaranteed.

In the Oracle JDK, the class `LinkedHashMap` reimplements the method `newKeyIterator()` which returns an instance of a class inheriting `LinkedHashIterator`. That one is ordered.

Comment: very valid one, +1 I dived into it to see this :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain that `LinkedHashMap#keySet().iterator()` iterates in specified order, so let me just add:

`ArrayList` Javadoc says about `ArrayList(Collection)`:

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

So it is guaranteed that the `ArrayList` items will be in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration order of a `LinkedHashSet` is guaranteed to be the same as the order in which keys are inserted (supposing you do not use the special constructor that allows you to request ordering by most-recent access instead).  You can find this in [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

I suppose you could argue that the iteration order guarantee applies only to the entry set, not to the other views, but the docs don't support that well (inasmuch as they refer to **the** iteration order), and in practice the collection views do share a common iteration order.

For its part, the constructor `ArrayList(Collection)` [is documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) to fill the list in the order that elements are returned by the specified `Collection`'s iterator.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this question [Does entrySet() in a LinkedHashMap also guarantee order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190083/does-entryset-in-a-linkedhashmap-also-guarantee-order) and noted in the [JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), iteration type operations are defined to be in the insertion order for `LinkedHashMap`. This affects the `keySet` as it does the `entrySet`.

The constructor of `ArrayList` will insert into the `List` in the iterator's order.

Those two conditions combined, means the API guarantees this behavior.

Comment: Good one, +1 for the references

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, Each one of you contributed valid points.

To summarize all answers,

**It is guaranteed that the order is maintained.**

As per [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html),

> LinkedHashMap is Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map
>   interface, with predictable iteration order.  This implementation
>   differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running
>   through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration
>   ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into
>   the map (insertion-order)

ie: *`LinkedHashMap` will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map*.

So  `LinkedHashMap#keySet()` will give me the same order in which the keys were inserted to the map, because
the  `LinkedHashMap#keySet().iterator()` iterates in specified order.

Going deep to the implementation of `iterator()` we can see that,

**LinkedHashMap implements the method newKeyIterator() which returns an instance of a class inheriting LinkedHashIterator, taking care of the 'ordering'**

```
// These Overrides alter the behavior of superclass view iterator() methods
Iterator<K> newKeyIterator()   { return new KeyIterator();   } ...  

private class KeyIterator extends LinkedHashIterator<K> {...

private abstract class LinkedHashIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> { ...
```

For this: `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());`
 The constructor *ArrayList(Collection)* is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) to fill the list in the order that elements are returned by the specified Collection's iterator.